# “would have” for assumptions

Tags: would, hypothetical

- If you live in a metro city, you would have seen this type of truck on street.
- As you would have seen us on the channel, we always act goofy.

In these two examples, “Would have” is used. And it is used to talk about past hypothetical situations, but there is not any hypothetical scenario, we are just giving an assumption or a possibility.Is this possible to use “would have” for past assumptions or possibilities?

Comment: I would find _will have_ more idiomatic (meaning 'it's likely that you have").

Comment: You don't say where you encountered these examples, but "channel" suggests an online video. These often contain examples that aren't the best choice of words, but are preserved because the videos are recorded and posted quickly and people are speaking unprepared, without scripts. I would just ignore these examples. The first one stands out less; the second seems just plain awkward, but can be understood as "As you you would have seen *if you were to have watched our other videos*." But adding "us" isn't doing the sentence any favors.

Comment: @KateBunting I have seen “will have + past participle” can be used to talk about past assumptions in the book advanced grammar in use, cambridge university. And I think “would have” and “will have” have the same meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Discarding these two examples as accidental ineloquent speech, but focusing on the core question:

> “Would have” is used ... to talk about past hypothetical situations, but there is not any hypothetical scenario, we are just giving an assumption or a possibility.Is this possible to use “would have” for past assumptions or possibilities?

Well yes, a past "assumption or possibility" *can be* a hypothetical scenario.

- *"If I **were** an early bird, **I would** eat something better than worms."* This is clearly hypothetical; I'm not a bird. But I'm speaking without reference to a timeline, so it's in a sort of "hypothetical present" and I just use "would."
- *"If I **were** Julius Caesar, I **would have** listened to that soothsayer and stayed home."* Clearly this is hypothetical; I never could have been Julius Caesar (in this lifetime anyway). And this flight of fancy is set in the past, so I use "would have."
- *"The milk was left out of the refrigerator? Don't blame me. If I **used** it, I'm sure I **would have** put it back."* This is not fantasy or impossibility. I'm not sure whether I used the milk or not, but *if* I did, it's a real event in the past. But I still use "would have" because I'm not sure. So here we have a scenario that is both a "past assumption or possibility" and also, in a sense, hypothetical.

Comment: In the 3rd example, how can he not be sure whether he used the milk or not? He is sure of himself that he has habit and he always put the milk back. Since this milk wasn't put back, he is sure that it wasn't him who used the milk. So, "If I had used it(which I didn't), I would have put it back" seems to be more fitting to this situation.

Comment: @Yunus It's of course possible that the speaker used it and put it back, but someone else left it out later. And as someone who nearly put the eggs into the freezer this morning, I can definitely imagine him being sure of his habit but unsure of whether he did anything at all!